# Copying files across computers in different networks using scp Mac Lion

Tags: macos, ssh

I forgot how to do this and I found [this other StackOverflow post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710946/copying-files-across-computers-using-ssh-and-mac-os-x-terminal) but now I'm getting this error:

> ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Permission denied lost
>   connection

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the permissions to the folder in which I want to write using `chmod` but I can't remember which ones do I need to change in the target computer.

Comment: Both that linked question and this one would be better suited for SuperUser since they have nothing to do specifically with programming.

Comment: could someone please move the question then?

Comment: You have to wait for the five close/move votes or a moderator. I'll hassle a mod.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error message, you are being denied access to that port on that IP address, before file permissions come into it. You need to check that:

1. The IP address you are trying to reach is accessible
2. The SSH server is running on that machine (Check in System Preferences -> Internet & Wireless -> Sharing that the 'remote login' option is checked)
3. There is no firewall on that machine, your machine or on the router which is blocking you from getting to port 22.

If that is all OK and you are still not able to connect, then you can start checking file permissions.